# What is the caret (^) for in a generic template in C++?

Tags: c++-cli, generic-collections

I see this code in c++ template examples:

```
void Main(array<String^>^ args)
```

but I don't understand the reason for the ^ terminating the String and closing angle bracket.

Is it to allow multiple types or something?  If someone could someone straighten me out, I would appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: This isn't C++. This is C++/CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is C++/CLI (C++ .NET). String^ is the equivalent of the String class in C#. It's different from std::string. Furthermore, array is a C++/CLI specific class (it's not a standard STL container).